# Objective-C: Formatting text in a string object within a plist

Tags: objective-c, string, formatting, plist

I am a new objective-c/iPhone developer and am wondering if there is any way to apply formatting to text within a string in a plist?

I have a plist that is an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains a few string objects, some of which I would like to contain lists and paragraphs of information. I am calling these strings and displaying them via labels in the UI.

Similar to using <li> and </li> or <b> and </b> in html, I would like to be able to specify parts of a string to be formatted when displayed as a bulleted list, bold, italic, etc.. How could this be accomplished?

With the help of some kind users on this site, I was able to embed the <li> and <b> tags within the xml plist file, however this just resulted in literally printing the tags on the screen.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: In other words, you want to know how to display HTML in your app?

Comment: I was primarily asking about how to format text in my app and if there was a simple solution to do this. I was just using the HTML tags as examples of what I was hoping to accomplish. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like the fact that your strings are in a plist has much to do with the issue. You'll be storing them that way regardless.  But if you want to render HTML-like formatting inside your UI, you have two choices:

1. Parse the data into an
   `NSAttributedString`, which is
   available starting in iOS 3.2. I
   believe you'll have to figure out
   how to get from the HTML
   representation to the right
   attributes in the string.
2. Use a `UIWebView` and render your HTML directly. This sounds heavyweight, esp for labels, and it probably would be, but you could try.

(Gist here is that there isn't a trivial answer to your question-- the Cocoa frameworks don't natively speak much HTML, and intra-string formatting isn't something that's necessarily easily done.)

Answer (score 1):

For HTML markup to work, you'll need to display the text in a UIWebView, not a UILabel. Check out the UIWebView documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString:baseURL:).

**Update:** In response to the other answer, I don't believe UILabel will correctly display an NSAttributedString even on iOS 4. Apple's recommended approach to doing styled text is to use a UIWebView (or draw the text yourself using [Core Text](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html), which is significantly more complicated).